# Why plot to a handle erase the previous object even with `hold on`?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Why does the line

```
plot(handle, 3, 3, 'ro')
```

clears the figure in handle even I set `hold on`?

### Full Code

```
hold on
figure(1);
hdl.r = subplot(121);
hdl.t = subplot(122);
plot(hdl.r, 1, 1, 'ro');
plot(hdl.r, 1, 2, 'ro');
```

There's always only one dot in my figure.

Comment: It's not because of that method: switching lines 3 and 4 and putting a hold on after setting up hdl.r will not clear the plot each time.

My guess would be that in your code, the hold on doesn't apply to the plotting handle hdl.r

Comment: It should work I guess. However @Daniel is straight to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold applies to axis, when having multiple axis I would always use the "long" version of hold (`hold(axis_handle,'on')`)

```
figure(1);
hdl.r = subplot(121);
hdl.t = subplot(122);
hold(hdl.r,'on');
hold(hdl.t,'on');
plot(hdl.r, 1, 1, 'ro');
plot(hdl.r, 1, 2, 'ro');
```